# Layers overlapping in custom table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I'm trying customise the table view cells in my iOS app, and have created two separate xib files. These are loaded in cellForRowAtIndexPath for two different kind of cells I have. But when cells are displayed some overlapping of layers occur as shown on screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r10q0gx2b4m86uj/cellissue2.png?dl=0).

Vertical line, circle and green dot are added in code inside my initialize method in CustomTableViewCell class using the following code.

```
// create right border layer
CALayer *rightBorder = [CALayer layer];
rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake (55.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, self.contentView.bounds.size.width);
rightBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.88 green:0.88 blue:0.88 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer:rightBorder];

    // create outer dot
    CALayer *outerDot = [CALayer layer];
    outerDot.frame = CGRectMake (49.0f, 14.0f, 12.0f, 12.0f);
    outerDot.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [outerDot setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [outerDot setCornerRadius:6.0];
    [outerDot setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [outerDot setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.88 green:0.88 blue:0.88 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
    [self.layer addSublayer:outerDot];

    // create inner dot
    CALayer *innerDot = [CALayer layer];
    innerDot.frame = CGRectMake (51.0f, 16.0f, 8.0f, 8.0f);
    innerDot.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.549 green:0.757 blue:0.322 alpha:1].CGColor;
    [innerDot setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [innerDot setCornerRadius:4.0];
```

This code works as expected for first cell only, and all other cells have vertical line over green dot displayed. But even these cells are displayed fine once they went off screen by scrolling the table view. 
Another confusing thing is vertical line in break cell. There is no code for adding this vertical line. 
Both cells are being loaded in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and which cell is returned depends on segmented control selection in the navigation bar, and it looks like this...

```
    if(_count == 1)
    {
        // dequeue break cell type
        UISessionBreakTableViewCell *breakCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:breakCellIdentifier];

        if (breakCell == nil) {
            NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyBreakTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            breakCell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        // set cell title

        return breakCell;
    }
    else
    {
        // dequeue session cell type
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

So, what I'm doing wrong, and why this vertical line is displayed over green dot in some cases, and in other it is not?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your initWithSegmentValue: you create the cell the load it from a xib and discard the cell just created (self=[nibArray...] replace "self" with a new object...). can you please add the whole cellForRow method?

Comment: cellForRow is pretty long to put it here... but it has check like this if([segment selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) to check which cell to initialise. And cell is initialised with code like this breakCell = [[UISessionBreakTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:breakCellIdentifier];